# More efficient way of using LINQ to compare two items?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, csom

I am updating records on a SharePoint list based on data from a SQL database.  Lets say my table looks something like this:

| VendorNumber | ItemNumber | Descrpition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | abc |
| 1001 | 2 | def |
| 1002 | 1 | ghi |
| 1002 | 3 | jkl |

There can be multiple keys in each table.  I am trying to make a generic solution that will work for multiple different table structures.  In the above example, **VendorNumber** and **ItemNumber** would be considered keys.

I am able to retrieve the SharePoint lists as c# `List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem>`

I need to search through the List to determine which individual `ListItem` corresponds to the current SQL datarow I am on.  Since both `ListItem` and `DataRow` allow bracket notation to specify column names, this is pretty easy to do using LINQ if you only have one key column.  **What I need is a way to do this if I have anywhere from 1 key to `N` keys.**  I have found this solution but realize it is very inefficient.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
List<string> keyFieldNames = new List<string>() { "VendorNumber", "ItemNumber" };
List<ListItem> itemList = MyFunction_GetSharePointItemList();
DataRow row = MyFunction_GetOneRow();

//this is the part I would like to make more efficient:
foreach (string key in keyFieldNames)
{
     //this filters the list with each successive pass.
     itemList = itemList.FindAll(item => item[key].ToString().Trim() == row[key].ToString().Trim());
}
```

**Edited to Add:**  Here is a link to the ListItem class documentation:
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem?view=sharepoint-csom)

While ListItem is not a DataTable object, its structure is very similar.  I have intentionally designed it so that both the ListItem and my DataRow object will have the same number of columns and the same column names.  This was done to make comparing them easier.

Comment: Can you share `ListItem`?

Comment: @ScottHannen I have edited the original post to include the documentation for ListItem.

Comment: Do they need to be trimmed?

Comment: Not sure.  Probably not.  The only reason they might need to be trimmed is if SharePoint Lists do something weird like add extra spaces at the end or something.  I will look into it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I stopped looking for an answer, I stumbled across one.   I have now realized that using a `.Where` is implemented using deferred execution.  This means that even though the `foreach` loop iterates several times, the LINQ query executes all at once.  This was the part I was struggling to wrap my head around.

My new sudo code:

```
List<string> keyFieldNames = new List<string>() { "VendorNumber", "ItemNumber" };
List<ListItem> itemList = MyFunction_GetSharePointItemList();
DataRow row = MyFunction_GetOneRow();

//this is the part I would like to make more efficient:
foreach (string key in keyFieldNames)
{
     //this filters the list with each successive pass.
     itemList = itemList.Where(item => item[key].ToString().Trim() == row[key].ToString().Trim());
}
```

I know that the `.ToString().Trim()` is still inefficient, I will address this at some point.  But for now at least my mind can rest knowing that the LINQ executes all at once.

Answer (score 1):

A quick optimization tip first:

- Create a `Dictionary<string, string>` to use instead of `row`

  ```
  List<string> keyFieldNames = new List<string>() { "VendorNumber", "ItemNumber" };
  DataRow row = MyFunction_GetOneRow();
  var rowData = keyFieldNames.ToDictionary(name=>row[name].ToString().Trim());
  foreach (string key in keyFieldNames)
  {
     itemList = itemList.FindAll(item => item[key].ToString().Trim() == rowData[key]);
  }
  ```

This will avoid doing the `ToString` & `Trim` on the same records over & over. That's probably taking 1/3rd to 1/2 the time of the loop. (The comparison is fast compared to the string manipulation)

Beyond that, all I can think of is to use reflection to build a specific function, on the fly to handle the comparison.  *BUT*, that would be a big effort, and I don't see it saving that much time. Basically, whatever you do, will still have to do the same basics: Lookup the values by key, and compare them. That's what's taking the majority of the time.